# How to use Xarray Alignment?

Tags: python, python-xarray

What is the equivalent of += in xarray? I tried using it in my code but the error stated that "automatic alignment is not supported for in-place operations". I went on the website they recommended and did more research but I am still stuck.

Thank you

I tried xr.align() and other calculations provided on different websites.

my code is as follows:

```
Time= []
a_foot= None
 
 
for file in glob.glob('*.nc'):
    #print(file)
    data= xr.open_dataset(file)
    lon= data['lon']
    lat= data['lat']
    time= data['time']
    foot= data['foot']

    if a_foot is None:
        a_foot=foot 
    else:
        a_foot += foot
    data.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just rewrite your code to not use the in-place operator `+=`, i.e. `a_foot = a_foot + foot`. You can also use `.copy()` to get around this.